# Windows 7 - Program wants to create shortcuts in C:\ProgramData when installed

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I am trying to install a program in Windows 7, the program wants to install Start Menu shortcuts in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. However, the installation fails and the error log states that the folder path is not found. Is there something I have to do to get the start menu shortcuts to install on this path?

Comment: Are you running the install program as an administrator?  That location is protected from modification by non-admin users.

Comment: I didn't know you need administrator rights to do that. is that the reason you think?

Comment: That would definitely be my first guess.  Unless you have a specific reason not to (or cannot on a certain machine), I would recommend all programs be installed via an admin account to prevent any possible blockages due to security restrictions.

Comment: Would that be the same on windows 2008 and 2008 r2 server machines?

Comment: @GilbertV - Why are you asking about Windows Server 2008 R2 if your using Windows 7?